# Bootstrap select menu styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to give my `<select>` menu a custom color and padding. As of now, It looks like this:

[image]

```css
select {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2A3F54;
}
```

```html
<select name="ad_account_selected" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

I want a small gap between the menus and the left side and give it the color of my sidebar ( seen around the menu above ). However, the button remains in the default color and even if I add `padding-left: 20px` the menu is stuck to the left side. Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your `data-style` to `btn-new` like this:

```
<select data-style="btn-new">
    ....
</select>
```

And then style that button like this:

```
.btn-new {
    background-color: #2A3F54;
}
```

Link to CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyBjrr

Comment: I did try this ( with the !important and .selectpicker). But it does not effect the color at all. Thats why I posted here. No matter what I do, the default styling prevails

Comment: Please provide a link to the site or recreate what you have done so far in jsFiddle.

Comment: The lighter blue is from `btn-primary` from this button rendered by bootstrap-select: `<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary">`

Comment: You will need to overwrite that instead.

Comment: Thats the question. I cant seem to override that. If I dont specify any `data-style` it defaults to `btn-default` and it appears white and not the color I want

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I was semi hoping the drop down will be the same color too instead of the boring white

Comment: Overwrite that with !important

Comment: I changed the color on hover by selecting it with `btn-new:hover`, does the menu dropdown have something like `btn:dropdown` ?